# Where in the C++ Standard does it say that the definition of a const built-in type variable must be initialized?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have been looking for this in N4713 for more than two hours to no avail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a C++14 draft which says, at 7.1.6.1 [dcl.type.cv]:

> As described in 8.5, the definition of an object or subobject of
>   const-qualified type must specify an initializer or be subject to
>   default-initialization

8.5 [dcl.init] says (clause 7):

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:

[for a non class, non array type]:

> ... no initialization is performed

And immediately follows with:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type
>   with a user-provided default constructor.

Therefore a `const` built-in must have an initializer, since otherwise it would be default-initialized and that is not allowed.

Comment: You were faster, have a +1

Comment: In future, apply Ctrl+F, "const", a trigger finger, and patience.

Comment: You're right. In N4713 it's in [dcl.type.cv]/2. Thanks.

Comment: It would be useful to add chapter tag (or however it's called) as a reference instead of a number. I.e. [dcl.init] those change less often than numbering. E.g. in the current draft as host by eel it's under [11.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#def:default-initialization).

Answer (score 4):

It's worded in quite an indirect way in N4713 [dcl.init] 11.6/7:

> If a program calls for the default-initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a const-default-
>   constructible class type or array thereof.

Not providing an initialiser causes an object to be default-initialised. As such, if it's `const` qualified and of a built-in type, it violates the "shall" rule above.